# Transformation of Vector in Dot Product is Interchangable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

In the answer key to a practice exam part of a proof says

> $$(Ax)\cdot y = x \cdot (A^T y)$$
>   Where $A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ and $y$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

What property of the dot product allows you to do this?

Comment: What happens if you transpose a scalar?

Comment: The sentence that you have after the equality is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that by simply looking at the definition of the dot product, $(Ax)\cdot y$ is equal to the one entry in the $1\times 1$ matrix $$y^T A x$$

Now observe that a $1\times 1$ matrix is symmetric. Hence this is also equal to $$x^T A^T y$$
whose only one entry is $(A^T y)\cdot x$.

Comment: Are you assuming that "the" definition of the dot product is $v\cdot w = w^Tv$? In most contexts I would expect that is just an (easy) characterization.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not saying that it *is* the definition, rather that by looking at the definition, and looking at $w^Tv$, you see immediately that they are equal.